# 'n' is undeclared error message as well as other possible programming errors

Tags: c++, function

I'm new to programming, and I'm trying to calculate n factorial, and I have no idea if this will even work but currently I am getting an error that says 'n' is undeclared. were are working with functions. I would really appreciate any tips you could give me about his program

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define PI 3.14159
#define e 2.72


void printDirections (void);
double readValue (void);
double calcNFact (double n);
void printN (void);

int main (void)
{
    double n, n_fact;
    double eq1, eq2, eq3, eq4;

    printf ("This program Calculates n factorial. \n");

// print directions
    printf ("Enter the value of n and the program\n will calculate n!");

// read the value of n from the user
    printf ("Enter n: /n");
    n = readValue ();

// Calculate n factorial
    n_fact = eq1 * eq2 * eq3 *eq4;


// print the results
    printN (n);

    return 0;





}

// Prints the directions
    void printDirections (void)
{
    printf ("Enter the value of n and the program\n will calculate n!");
    return ;
}

// Read the value of n from the user
double readValue (void)
{
    double value;
    printf ("Enter n: /n");
    scanf ("%lf", &value);

    return (value);


}

// Calculate and return n factorial, pass in n
double calcNFact (double n)
{
 double n_fact, eq1, eq2, eq3, eq4;
 eq1 = ((2 * n) + (1 / 3)) * PI;
 eq2 = sqrt (eq1);
 eq3 = pow (e, -n);
 eq4 = pow (n, n);
 n_fact = eq1 * eq2 * eq3 * eq4;

 return n_fact;

}
//print n and n factorial
void printN (void)
{
  printf ("\n n: %.1f \n", n);
  printf ("\n n!: %.2f \n", n_fact);

  return;

}
```

Comment: Aside from the obvious, which is `n` and `n_fact` being undefined in `void printN(void)` (per the several answers), the line `n_fact = eq1 * eq2 * eq3 * eq4` is worrisome, as none of those values have been initialized. Logic aside, `double calcNFact( double n )` is never called. Also, don't be afraid to call the `printDirections()` function you created. Additionally, in the case of *your* `void` functions, it is not necessary to `return`, although there are conditional cases where this may be necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Your `printN` function can't read the variables `n` and `n_fact` because they are out of scope.

[Variable Scope in C++](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_variable_scope.htm)

Also, the parameter signature in your function definition `void printN (void)` is not consistent with your function call `printN (n)`.

Answer (score 1):

`n` is undeclared inside `printN` function (as well as `n_fact`). `printN` should accept them as parameters:

```
void printN (double n, double n_fact) {...}
```

So you call it:

```
printN(n, n_fact);
```

Comment: @polarysekt yep, thanks, my brain just couldn't think of `N` as `double`

Comment: where do I put this though? I placed in in each printN and both at the same time and I kept getting an error message

Comment: @SJP Post your updated code. Point exact line where error occurs.

Comment: You need it at the declaration `void printN( double n, double n_fact );` instead of `void printN (void);` and at the definition `void printN( double n, double n_fact ) { ... }` instead of `void printN( void ) { ... }`. And as @AntonSavin explains in his answer, you call it with both parameters as `printN(n, n_fact)`.

Answer (score 0):

Your variables `n`/`n_fact` are not in the scope of the function `printN`, which is why it is saying "undeclared".

One solution would be to pass the values of `n`/`n_fact` to your function `printN`.